# Deleting a variable as an property identifier of object global(This) in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `node v18.4.0`.

```
"use strict";
var x = 1; // Declare a global variable
console.log("x", x);
console.log("globalThis.x", globalThis.x);
console.log("global.x", global.x);
console.log("delete globalThis.x", delete globalThis.x);
console.log("globalThis.x", globalThis.x);
console.log("x", x);
console.log("delete global.x", delete global.x);
console.log("global.x", global.x);
console.log("x", x);
```

and it prints

```
x 1
globalThis.x undefined
global.x undefined
delete globalThis.x true
globalThis.x undefined
x 1
delete global.x true
global.x undefined
x 1
```

It seems that var is not setting a global variable... My objective was to set a global variable and then delete it.

Comment: "*My objective was to set a global variable and then delete it.*" you cannot delete a variable. Only properties of objects. So, the entire plan was wrong. Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) anyway. Have you considered *not* using global variables?

Comment: @VLAZ But aren't global variables properties of the 'global' object?

Comment: No. They *create* a property on the global object but that's *in addition* to the binding itself. So `var foo` will create binding named `foo` and also `global.foo`. The two things aren't linked where nuking the property nukes the binding.